# Obscured SharedPreference , BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted

Tags: java, android, encryption

Following code was working fine but on a Samsung SM-G950F, Android OS 8.0.0, it crashes:

```
private String encrypt(String value) {

  try {
    final byte[] bytes = value != null ? value.getBytes(UTF8) : new byte[0];
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(SEKRIT));
    Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID).getBytes(UTF8), 20));
    return new String(Base64.encode(pbeCipher.doFinal(bytes), Base64.NO_WRAP), UTF8);

  } catch (Exception e) {
    return value;
  }

}

private String decrypt(String value) {
  try {
    final byte[] bytes = value != null ? Base64.decode(value, Base64.DEFAULT) : new byte[0];
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(SEKRIT));
    Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    pbeCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID).getBytes(UTF8), 20));
    return new String(pbeCipher.doFinal(bytes), UTF8);

  } catch (Exception e) {
    return value;
  }
}
```

here is the full error message:

```
 Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted
    at com.edaf.utils.ObscuredSharedPreferences.decrypt(SourceFile:185)
    at com.edaf.utils.ObscuredSharedPreferences.getString(SourceFile:134)
    at com.edaf.utils.Utils.getFromGlobals(SourceFile:145)
```

I changed return value on crash but  I am sure it wont help

Answer (score 0):

That piece of code was *designed to fail* if encryption was performed on one device and decryption is performed on a different device. If `Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)` returns a different string then the `salt` parameter of the [`PBEParameterSpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/PBEParameterSpec.html) constructor will be different.

Once the salt is different, then a different key will be calculated from the password, and your decryption is *likely* to fail with a padding related exception. The salt is *used to* create a different value even if passwords are identical (using *only* the ID is rather stupid though, because using the same ID will result in identical passwords, even in different applications).

If the decryption doesn't fail then you'll get a garbage plaintext by the way.

---

There are endless issues within the code of the question, for instance using single DES and a 20 iteration count and non-authenticated encryption. I could post a page long review, but instead I urge you to read a book on modern crypto, and revise your protocol ASAP.

Comment: @Maarteen do you have some code to replace with  'Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)'  untill I finish a book on modern crypto

Comment: Generate a random salt of at least 8 bytes, and prefix it to the ciphertext, then use that. Retrieve, remove and reuse it as salt for decryption, of course. Note that it looks like the salt is generated on purpose this way; you may break some kind of security rule for the product if you do so (although I presume the security design / threat model is non-existent for this kind of code)